# Skip Characters in Oracle TO_DATE function

Tags: sql, date, oracle11g, to-date

I'm importing data that has SQL Server formatted dates in a .tsv (`yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.mmm`) into an Oracle database using SQL Developer's Import Data wizard.

How can I ignore the `.mmm` characters for importing them into a DATE column? I cannot seem to find an answer to this; I get that DATE columns don't hold milliseconds, but why can't I ignore specific patterns in the TO_DATE call?

Also note that because I'm not generating the TO_DATE calls, I cannot `SUBSTRING` or otherwise manipulate the .tsv's value during the import.

[image: Import Data Wizard - Date]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the pound sign (`#`) for this:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2015-01-01 01:00:00.999', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.###') FROM dual;
--> 01/01/2015 01:00:00
```

---

I did not find this in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212), so I can't say why, but these also work:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('01_','hh24#') FROM dual;

SELECT TO_DATE('01:01:01.0xx','hh24:mi:ss.###') FROM dual;
```

These don't seem to work:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('010','hh24#') FROM dual;

SELECT TO_DATE('01:01:01.xxx','hh24:mi:ss.###') FROM dual;
```

---

This seems to be undocumented, but you seem to be able to interchange the punctuations without problems:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2015-01;01 11:12/13',
               'yyyy.mm,dd_hh-mi ss') FROM dual;
--> 01/01/2015 11:12:13
```

---

You can use *Character literals, enclosed in double quotation marks* if you know which text to ignore:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('foo2015bar-01-!#%}01', '"foo"yyyy"bar"-mm-"!#%}"dd') FROM dual;
--> 01/01/2015
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Does it stand in for any character, including `.` and `:`? Something like `TO_DATE('junk2015.a03.b27c13:55d.33.888efg', '####yyyy.#mm.#dd#hh24.mi#.ss#######')`

Comment: I did not find it in the documentation, but it does not seem to work like this. `('01_','hh24#')` works, while `('010','hh24#')` doesn't. `('01:01:01.0xx','hh24:mi.ss.###')` works, but `('01:01:01.xxx','hh24:mi.ss.###')` doesn't.

Comment: So it has to start with a number? Hmm. Note the `.` in the format string between mi and ss working for `:`.

Comment: This worked, but I'm still confused as to how the `TO_DATE` is working with these characters: `#:.` (it also works with `SELECT TO_DATE('2015-01-01 01:00:00.999', 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24.mi:ss....') FROM dual;`. Could you add some detail on how this works?

Comment: I tried to edit my findings into my answer, but I could not find it in the documentation. Feel free to ask another question, linking to this one - maybe someone else knows how this works in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail!

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to do this; Oracle will automagically convert a timestamp into a date if you attempt to add fractional seconds to a date column. Use [`TO_TIMESTAMP()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions213.htm#SQLRF06142) instead and embrace the fractional seconds.

```
SQL> create table tmp_test (dt date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into tmp_test
  2  select to_timestamp('2015-03-24 13:10:03.654','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.FF3')
  3    from dual;

1 row created.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.FF3';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from tmp_test;

DT
-------------------
2015-03-24 13:10:03

SQL>
```

Comment: I appreciate that there are workarounds for it; but in this case I'm using the Import Data wizard in SQL Developer, the destination column is a `DATE` and all I have to modify is the format string of `TO_DATE()` only, not `TO_TIMESTAMP()`. What I'm looking for is any notation that will ignore the character at that position: for example `yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss****` or something that will effectively ignore the milliseconds with a `TO_DATE()`.